# SQL Server : join with criteria

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a fairly simple SQL question. I have a query that pulls up data from multiple tables. Just got a new request to join another table. A simplified version is created here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9698/4

I want all records from the left (`Prod1`) table. There will be multiple entries on the `ProdAttr` table for each `ProdID`. But I want to pull up only the ones where the criteria meets in the following query. I'm not sure if I should use join or union! Please advise.

```
select 
    P1.*, PA.AttrDesc 
from 
    prod1 P1
left join 
    ProdAttr PA on P1.ProdID = PA.ProdID
where 
    AttrID= 4 and AttrVal=68;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `left join` fails, columns from the `ProdAttr` table are filled with `null`.  In those cases your `where` will filter out the rows, because `null` is neither 4 nor 68:

```
where AttrID= 4 and AttrVal=68;
```

Move the condition to the `on` clause like:

```
select P1.*, PA.AttrDesc from prod1 P1
  left join ProdAttr PA
  on P1.ProdID = PA.ProdID
     and AttrID= 4 and AttrVal=68;
```

Now the condition is only used to find rows in `ProdAttr`, not as a filter on the result of the join between `prod1` and `ProdAttr`.

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know I can add conditions within the join clause. I forgot to mention one thing. so if there's a match, I'm showing the attribute description but if there isn't a match, can I add some text?

Comment: You could use `isnull` to show an alternative text, like `select P1.*, isnull(PA.AttrDesc, 'Not Found') from ...`

Comment: You're the boss. kudos to you.